# Make Biblatex show normal cites even if citation is repeated in a table

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, maxbibnames=99, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
```

for my thesis. When I consecutively cite the same source twice, the second citation is shown as "ibid." (or "ebd." in German). This is generally ok, but for a certain table in my document I would like this to behave differently.

Is it possible to switch this "abbreviated citing" off for a certain stretch of text? What are these "ibid citations" called, anyway? I tried searching the web but I found it hard because I don't know the terminology.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're asking, but "ibid." is short for *ibidem*, which means "the same thing" in Latin.

Comment: Did that happen in a floating table? Because I think I read somewhere (apparently p. 236 §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) that `biblatex` disables citation tracking in floats automatically.

Comment: @AndrewCashner This is not what I was asking, but your answer is still interesting. Strange that the German translation used instead of "ibidem" is a little different (at least I think so). Anyway, do you know how to call this kind of citations which contain (only) "ibid."?

Comment: @moewe I do not use the table in a float, but I just tried it and you're right. It works.

Comment: @anjuta Actually, I realized I was wrong: It means "in the same place." Not that it matters!

Comment: Ahhh, I see, when I hear table in a LaTeX context I immediately think of a floating table, that's why I was slightly confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose code where you don't want the "ibid" mechanism to work in

```
\citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
blah
\citetrackertrue\pagetrackertrue\backtrackertrue
```

Depending on whether you find it logical to directly pick up the state from before this block you might or might not add `\citereset`.
See p. 91 and p. 195 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for an explanation of these commands.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, maxbibnames=99, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilde} and  \cite{wilde}

\citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
\cite{wilde} and  \cite{wilde}
\citetrackertrue\pagetrackertrue\backtrackertrue

\cite{wilde} and  \cite{wilde}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You could also define a new cite command along the lines of

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeNT}
  {\citetrackerfalse
   \pagetrackerfalse
   \backtrackerfalse
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeyear}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I'll keep the rest in mind depending on what I will need for my thesis. For now, switching this manually on/off is enough. Do you happen to know this mechanism's name?

Comment: @anjuta I'm not entirely sure which mechanism you refer to. `biblatex` has a boolean value that tracks whether the citetracker is active. If you load certain styles, this boolean `citetracker` is set to <true>, to disable tracking we make it <false> via `\boolfalse{citetracker}` and then turn cite tracking on again with `\booltrue{citetracker}`. When I searched the documentation just now, I found that it champions another (equivalent) way of doing this.